# Require client cert for all requests except CORS preflight

Tags: apache, ssl, cors, client-certificates

I have an Apache server which uses SSL and requires client certificates for all incoming requests - all other requests are terminated immediately. This is fine in most cases but I would like to allow a CORS preflight to be sent to the server without client cert. The response to the preflight should be static.

Any ideas on how I can configure this in the Apache config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered something that may be related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753542/3338053).

Basically put your auth or ssl stuff between `<LimitExcept OPTIONS>` and `</LimitExcept>`

Comment: I ended up with `<Location />` _line break_ `SSLVerifyClient  require` _line break_ `SSLVerifyDepth   10` _line break_ `<Limit OPTIONS>` _line break_ `SSLVerifyClient optional` _line break_ `</Limit>` _line break_ `</Location>` but it seems your solution would have worked as well :)