# CORS with basic AuthType

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cors

I am trying to secure a JSON file via htaccess basic auth, with CORS ability

My code is split across two domains:

- `api.example.com`, which contains `test.json` and is protected via `.htaccess`
- `site.example.com`, which contains `index.html` and is trying to make a request to `api.example.com/test.json`

---

If the .htaccess file in api.example.com does not contain authentication, CORS works correctly:

```
<Files "test.json">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://site.example.com"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
</Files>
```

However, once authentication is added to the .htaccess file, cors throws an error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.example.com/test.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Broken .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home/passwd"

<Files "test.json">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://site.example.com"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
</Files>
```

Here is request in api.example.com/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.example.com/test.json", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("user:password"));
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Adding `Authorization` headers to your request makes it non-simple so you need to be able to respond successfully to pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Comment: This might help. [CORS - how to ignore authentication for OPTIONS preflight request in Apache's httpd.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556495/cors-how-to-ignore-authentication-for-options-preflight-request-in-apaches-ht)

Comment: Phil, can you please clarify? Wrapping the auth in <LimitExcept OPTIONS> did not seem to do the trick

Comment: Did you add a rewrite rule to respond to `OPTIONS` requests with a 200 status (part `(a)` in the question)?

Comment: Actually, wrapping in <LimitExcept OPTIONS> did work! My browser was just caching the CORS message